# How can I get MvcHtmlString from DropDownListFor in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I've tried this:

```
public ActionResult RebuildDropDown(string selectedItem)
{
    bool error = false;
    MvcHtmlString drop = null;

    try
    {
        var helper = new HtmlHelper<Asset>(new ViewContext(), new ViewPage());

        //SelectList made from List<SelectListItem>
        var selectList = Asset.CriarSelectList(selectedItem);

        //x.Id is string
        drop = helper.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, selectList);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        error = true;
    }

    return Json(new { error, drop });
}
```

Always getting null ref in this line:

```
drop = helper.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, selectList);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why? If you're trying to fetch a html fragment via ajax, then use a view. Otherwise return json and process it into html dom nodes in javascript.